# Is there a more terse command to determine checkbox values?

Tags: jquery

I'm presently using the below line of code to determine the clicked values of a group of checkboxes.  Is there a more terse command I can use?  Here's what I'm using:

```
$("input[name=NameOfCheckBoxHere]:checked").map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(",")
```

Comment: Not really! using map to return the value of several elements seems about right.

Comment: Agreed, if you need a comma separated string of values like that, this is a good way to do it. If you want it a tiny bit more terse, you can leave out the `","` in the `.join()` because that's the default. OTOH one might argue that the code is more clear with the explicit `","`.